# While vertical center div using table cell, I need to make the div width 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm using Table cell to vertical center contend within DIV its works fine, Now i need to make the content div width to 100%, How can i do that ?

Source Code

```
  <div style="display: table; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
     <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
       <div>
         Div Contend
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**This is how now its look like,**
[image]
**This how i want**
[image: I want div look like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width to 100% and add `text-align: center` to the parent div containing the text.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: table; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="wrap" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div>
      Div Contend
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, Raashid. Try not to use inline styling. It will make you to mess up the code :)

Answer (score 2):

Surely adding `width: 100%` to the div that has `display: table` will solve your problem?

PS: If you're looking to Vertical Center contents ( not conten**d** :P ), try using Flexbox!

---

**Vertical Centering with Flexbox**

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/